# BackgroundImage is not setting properly in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, image, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save the backgroundImage of the ViewPager, using SharedPreferences and load that image as background when we run the app for the next time. It works fine in the emulator but not in the device. Please help me in solving this.Thanks,

Here is my code..

```
 SlidePagerActivity.mPager.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.snow);

    SharedPreferences backgroundImage = getSharedPreferences("BGPREFS", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor bgEditor = backgroundImage.edit();
    bgEditor.putInt("imgValue", R.drawable.app_bg_snowfall);
    bgEditor.commit();
```

Comment: still not clear. did not get value of preferences?

Comment: Got the value from Sharedpreferences..works fine in the emulator but not in the device (Samsung Galaxy Grand).

Comment: try this way   `SharedPreferences backgroundImage = getSharedPreferences("BGPREFS", Context.PRIVATE);`

Comment: Ya. But since i am saving the image to SharedPreferences in one class and getting the image in another class i am using getSharedPreferences("BGPREFS",Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

Comment: used `Context.PRIVATE` instead of `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

To put in SharedPreferences

```
  SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("myApp", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();  
    editor.putInt("NewBackground", idImage);  
    editor.commit();
```

To get the Preference:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("myApp", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
int myNewIntValue = sp.getInt("NewBackground", 0);
```

and finally use it. MyNewIntValue